# The title of a particular node became part of the breadcrumbs of administration pages

Tags: 9, breadcrumbs

In the Claro theme, I have the *System breadcrumb* block in the *Breadcrumb* region. The breadcrumb shows *Homepage > [Title for node 444] > Structure > [Administration page title]* instead of *Homepage > Structure > [Administration page title]*, where *[Title for node 444]* is the title for the node whose ID is 444, and *[Administration page title]* is the title for the shown administrative page.

Upgrading to Drupal 10.1.2 didn't solve the issue.

How can I remove the node title, which should not be there since the shown page is an administrative page not related to nodes nor to that node in particular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this problem by assigning an admin alias

```
/admin/structure
```

to a node. Then the title of the node is displayed in the breadcrumbs.

To solve this problem search for the alias in the alias table:

```
/admin/config/search/path?search=admin
```

Delete the alias and clear the cache.

You might also want to check the admin menu for an entry pointing at the node.